# Excel vba using dictionary loop for extraction of data

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is able to loop my files in the folder and add the file names into the dictionary, however when i add my extraction code in, its supposed to extract data from every single file in the folder into one excel sheet and for file 1 should be in range A2:M2, file 2 in range A3:M3 and so on. but despite being able to extract data from every file, everytime the first file will be written to range A2:M2 but as it continues to the next file, it will overwrite data from first file onto the same range A2:M2 even though file 2 data should be written into A3:M3 and file 3 into A4:M4 and so on.

May i know how i can fix this issue, thank you so much.

```
Public Dict As Object
Sub EEE()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, ofile As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\")

If Dict Is Nothing Then
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.Add Key:="filename", Item:=ofile
End If

For Each ofile In oFolder.Files
    If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)) Then

' start of extraction code
            Dim a As Range

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
            Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(ofile.path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Book1"
            Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Book1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

            Dim LastRow As Long
                LastRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

            wks.Cells(LastRow, 6).value = ofile.Name

        Set a = wksData.Columns("A:A").Find("  test1234         : ", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
        wks.Cells(LastRow, 1) = Split(a.value, ":")(1)
        End If

                wkbData.Close False
' end of extraction code 
                Range("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Range("A1").AutoFilter

        Debug.Print "A: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
        Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1

    Else
        'skip
        Debug.Print "E: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)

    End If

Next ofile

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If ColA in your summary sheet is not populated, then the next time you determine LastRow it will end up on the same row as the previous iteration.  You should always put something in ColA if you're going to use that column to find the next empty row.

Answer (score 0):

Following from my comment above:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 '<< this can be outside your loop

For Each ofile In oFolder.Files
    If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)) Then

        Dim a As Range

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
        Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(ofile.path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets(1) ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

        wks.Cells(LastRow, 6).value = ofile.Name

        Set a = wksData.Columns("A:A").Find("  test1234         : ", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
             wks.Cells(LastRow, 1) = Split(a.value, ":")(1)
        Else
             wks.Cells(LastRow, 1) = "No Data!"
        End If

        wkbData.Close False

        Debug.Print "A: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
        Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1

        LastRow = LastRow +1 '<< increment the row

    Else
        Debug.Print "E: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
    End If

Next ofile
```

Comment: thanks so much! even though its not the answer that solved my problem, but it did manage to guide me through and solve my problem, really appreciate your help!